# Filedata in upload script not storing data in DB

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
// Database configuration
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "bdlvjvgd_pitcher";
$password = "!";
$database = "bdlvjvgd_pitcher";

// Maximum file size (in bytes)
$maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB

// Connect to database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_FILES["image"])) {
    // Check if file exceeds maximum size
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > $maxFileSize) {
        die("Error: File size exceeds the maximum limit.");
    }

    // Get file details
    $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $filedata = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

    // Prepare SQL statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (filename, filetype, filesize, filedata) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssib", $filename, $filetype, $filesize, $filedata);

    // Execute SQL statement
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Image uploaded successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "Error uploading image: " . $stmt->error;
    }

    // Close statement
    $stmt->close();
}

// Close database connection
$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Upload Image</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" required>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    filename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    filetype VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    filesize INT NOT NULL,
    filedata LONGBLOB NOT NULL
);
```

This is the script for upload images to the server -- and it says successfully upload, in the DB however, the filedate field is empty -- if I manually insert in the DB it works fine... attached image of the SQL 2 were uploaded manually in the Myphp and the other two using the script -- field set to LONGBLOB

was expecting the image tp upload properly

Comment: in such cases you hould temporary enable general logging and see what happens in the data base.

Comment: my original script uploaded all information except the actual BLOB data -- that field is blank in the DB -- I've checked the code again, it's accurate but something blocking the data from posting?

Comment: data must be saved as string, depending how bug the data is, you should think about saving the data as file and only save the reference

Comment: this the error array -- Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => tes.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpaCKmAV [error] => 0 [size] => 5558 ) )

Comment: please post the complete code, to see what you changed always edit your question

Comment: The above has been edited to exactly what I'm running -- if someone can load that script on there server and see if it works for them or educate me on why it's not... also added the SQL I used to create the table